# How force papertrail to store an object with only meta data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paper-trail-gem

I've looked in to [how to store meta data for a paper trail versioned object](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#storing-metadata) and it seems easy enough.  Problem is I want to be able to store that meta data without making any actual changes to the object.  Calling .save or .touch or just using .update_attributes!(:updated_at => Time.now) doesn't create a new version.

Anyone know a way to force paper trail to store a version that doesn't have any changes but has meta data?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue in Papertrail:

https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/issues/329

From the issue:

> So touch doesn't create a version because it doesn't trigger ActiveRecord::Callbacks like a normal update does, and PaperTrail generates versions for updates from a before_update callback.

Right now there doesn't appear to be a way to configure Paper Trail to do it automatically, but there's a .touch_with_version method you can explicitly call on an instance that will create a new version with just the updated timestamp

https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/blob/cd9233ba0be53c53ceb96be3cd23ece8254f4c5a/lib/paper_trail/has_paper_trail.rb#L263

Comment: This looks promising, but when I tried it, it seems like .touch_with_version doesn't create a new version unless there are changes to tracked attributes.  So it doesn't help for the problem of "I want to save a version, but only the metadata has changed".